# Why is the Image not showing on a view.xaml when it is removed from NavigationView.PaneHeader from MainWindow.xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I don't understand why these are connected. I removed the Pane header image and when I remove this image, it gets removed from the Page as well (even though the `<Image source.../>` still exists in `HomePageView.xaml`. I don't understand how and why they are connected?

Image showing when Pane header image code exists
[image: Image showing when Header image entry is there]

Same code snipped and program however only deleted 3 lines which should only remove the pane header image?

[image]

The Style is defined in `App.xaml` which can be seen here:

```
<Application
    x:Class="Ankara_Online.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Ankara_Online">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                    <Style x:Key="Logo" TargetType="Image">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="Assets/TRvACC/trvacc_logo_transparent.png"/>
                    </Style>
                    <Style x:Key="defaultTextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000000" />
                        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Poppins" />
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                    </Style>
                </ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                    <Style x:Key="Logo" TargetType="Image">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="Assets/TRvACC/trvacc_logo_transparent_2.png"/>
                    </Style>
                    <Style x:Key="defaultTextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF" />
                        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Poppins" />
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                    </Style>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- Other app resources here -->
            <!--directories etc. shared resoruces-->
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

---

**UPDATE**

I was trying to understand why this is happening and found out that it's not related to `Style`. In fact, even if I manually give source to `Image` it still does not show.

Comment: The entire ``HomePageView`` is not rendered? or just the image? What happens when you put those 3 lines back?

Comment: HomePageView is rendered however the image is not rendered. If I put those 3 lines back then the image does re-appear.

Comment: I tried this by bringing your code to a minimal project but failed to reproduce your issue. The images are rendered. Can you share a minimal reproducible project? A GitHub repo maybe?

Comment: Repo is here https://github.com/cptalpdeniz/Ankara_Online/ however it does not include .sln or .csproj

Comment: I found what's happening but not why it's happening. I checked the Live Property Explorer and it seems UriSource is `ms-appx:///Views/Assets\Images\logo.png` however this is wrong, it should be just `ms-appx:///Assets\Images\logo.png` (not sure about the slash character).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, it seemed like the issue seemed to be related to `NavigationView.PaneHeader` image to be present or not. However, upon further investigation, I found out that this was not the issue. The issue was due to relative vs absolute path when addressing an image and passing it as `Image` `Source`. Upon checking the Live Property Explorer, I found out that the value for `UriSource` for `Image` was wrong. When declaring the image path by doing

```
<Style x:Key="HeaderLogo" TargetType="Image">
    <Setter Property="Source" Value="Assets/Images/logo.png" />
</Style>
```

When a Page or Frame is rendered within `./Views` folder, the `UriSource` value was being converted to `ms-appx:///Views/Assets\Images\logo.png` which is not correct. The correct format should be without the /Views in the beginning of the path. To fix this, I changed the `Value` to native `Uri`:

```
<Style x:Key="TRvACC_LOGO" TargetType="Image">
     <Setter Property="Source" Value="ms-appx:///Assets/Images/logo.png" />
</Style>
```

Which resulted in success! Image is being displayed correctly.